what does TD(Transport Dependent) mean on ATA8-ACS document?
The explanation of TD in the ATA8-ACS document is as shown in the figure below, but I did not understand what it does.

When I use the ATA protocol for data transmission, such as using the identify command (as shown in the figure below), what should I fill in the TD bit in the device field?

